# How to arrange items in ToolStripControlHost given by GoDiagram

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, toolstrip

I have a control from GoDiagram called GoTextToolStrip class.

It is hosted by a ToolStripControlHost and it is used on a ToolStrip in Visual Studio.

More information about this class is available in this [link](http://www.nwoods.com/products/godiagram/docs/GoWin5.0.0/webframe.html#Northwoods.Go.Draw~Northwoods.Go.Draw.GoTextToolStrip.html).

Here is how it looks:
[image]

Now I want to arrange the controls in GoTextToolStrip class from two rows to a row as shown in the image below:
[image]

I have contacted GoDiagram support team and its reply said

> They are just .NET controls though, so it's probably possible to do simply through .NET calls.

Question:
1) How to arrange the controls in GoTextToolStrip into a single row?
Is it possible to do it? If yes, which .NET calls/functions/properties I should use/override?

Please ask me if you need more details.

I have attached my codes sample and a screen cast video.

[Sample Project](http://www.filedropper.com/testgotoolstrip)

[GoDiagram DLL](http://www.filedropper.com/godiagramdll) - please add reference to it if you need

[Screen cast video](http://www.filedropper.com/2016-04-281038) - please view it in any internet browser like Google Chrome, Internet Explorer, etc.

Thank you.

Comment: Where is the code you used to generate the `GoTextToolStrip`?

Comment: @Xiaoy312, I do not have the code to produce GoTextToolStrip. It is from a DLL reference library from GoDiagram. I can send you a sample project if you need.

Comment: I'm not familiar with GoDiagram, but you could have a look at the `LayoutStyle` property in the Toolstrip's properties and try changing it to HorizontalStackWithOverflow.

Comment: @DavidWilson, I have tried to adjust LayoutStyle but it is not working also. You can refer to the sample project and my screencast video.

Comment: I've spent (too long<g>) looking through the various public and protected methods and it seems that the Layout is protected code and it can't be altered. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the [`ToolStrip.LayoutStyle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstrip.layoutstyle(v=vs.110).aspx) Property to achieve what you want :

```
__GoTextToolStrip__.GetCurrentParent().LayoutStyle = ...
```

> Flow 
>   Specifies that items flow horizontally or vertically as necessary.
>
> **HorizontalStackWithOverflow**    
>   Specifies that items are laid out horizontally and overflow as necessary.
>
> StackWithOverflow    
>   Specifies that items are laid out automatically.
>
> Table    
>   Specifies that items are laid out flush left.
>
> VerticalStackWithOverflow    
>   Specifies that items are laid out vertically, are centered within the control, and overflow as necessary.

Comment: Sorry, I could not find LayoutStyle from GoTextToolStrip as it inherits from  ToolStripControlHost, not ToolStrip. You can check here: [link]http://www.nwoods.com/products/godiagram/docs/GoWin5.0.0/webframe.html#Northwoods.Go.Draw~Northwoods.Go.Draw.GoTextToolStrip.html

Comment: @hunterex You can get the `ToolStrip` via `ToolStripControlHost.GetCurrentParent()`.

Comment: I have tried your method but it is not working. I have uploaded sample project and a screen cast video in my post above.